# I know how to program, how do I learn how to wire things up?

Tags: tutorial

I'm computer science student, I know:

- some basic VHDL
- program in C or assembler
- basic electrical laws (ohm law, kirchhoff, ..)
- basic electronic parts (diode, tranistor, ..)

What I don't know are those practical things like:

- where to put pull up resistor and why? What resistance do i choose?
- it seems like there are randomly putted capacitors all round circuits and i have no idea why
- i dont know what to do in order to not blow up processor
- that crystal trick that generates clock .. how do i compute the numbers?

I have theoretical background, but that doesn't tell me anything about how to handle interference and those "practical" guidlines. Do you know any good youtube videos or books?

I know i could just use arduino, but that's so expensive! And it's quite overkill for some basic projects like: light up led if cat passes laser latch for 1 minute.

Comment: An Arduino is a means, not an end. Lots of people use it as an end, but it really isn't.

Comment: I'm soryy, I'm not so strong in english. What does means and end mean?

Comment: Lots of people use the Arduino as a final component in their project. It's not supposed to be used for that, it's a tool for exploring potential solutions. The final result should be a MCU on a circuit board.

Comment: Do I understand it correctly, that i will programe my arduino, test it using board, buy new aurduino processor, program it using arduino board and deploy it to application (custom board)?

Comment: That's about right. Although it wouldn't be an "Arduino processor", it would be a [AVR MCU](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/avr/default.aspx). Unless you use a Due. Then things get trickier.

Comment: "How do I learn to wire things up?" This is too broad a question. "Where to put pull-up resistor and why? What resistance do I choose?" This is a good question on its own; but if you spend a moment and search this site, you'll find that many questions addressing pull-up resistors have already been asked and answered. Ask a ***specific*** question if you find that, after reading the other questions and answers, you are still unclear on something.

Comment: I don't have problem specifically with pull up resistors, I have problem lacking practical skills. The answer I was seeking was resource where to find those knowledge. I don't want to ask specifically, because I might miss something I didn't know I should ask about.

Comment: There are a lot of places to find knowledge, e.g. [allaboutcircuits.com](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/), for example. ***This*** very site is also a great resource for asking experts in the field. But you have to provide specific cases. Asking about recommendations for learning resources or products is not on-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> where to put pull up resistor and why? What resistance do i choose?

Pullup/Pulldown resistors provide default High/Low value for a signal, that would otherwise be *floating* (All it's drivers are tri-stated). We don't want floating signals, because when fed to digital inputs, they create spurious transitions, can put the logic into undefined states, and stuff like that... Generally, anything in the order *4k7* - *20k* will be good enough.

> it seems like there are randomly putted capacitors all round circuits
>   and i have no idea why

Capacitors in most digital use-cases work for storing energy. Digital circuitry needs pretty stable power supply - the problem is, the switching inside these very circuits creates very rapid, short and repetitive power draw. This is dealt with using *filtering*, *blocking* and *decoupling* capacitors. They are all in parallel on the same power rail, but differ in size, ESL, ESR, capacitance, etc...

> i dont know what to do in order to not blow up processor

You read the datasheets. Right pin connections and stable power supply is good for starters.

> that crystal trick that generates clock .. how do i compute the
>   numbers?

Crystals come in *a)* specific frequencies and *b)* specific load capacitances. They generally need a pair of load capacitors connected between ground and each end of the crystal in order to work properly. Again, the IC's manufacturer will likely provide you with equations/tables for getting these cap values.